# IOException when opening credentials.json

Tags: java, android, json, ioexception

I'm making an app to connect to the Google Calendar API, but whenever I try to load the client secrets, an IOException jumps.

I've tried from changing the path where the file is stored (first it was in app folder, then I moved it to `res/assets`) to changing the way to open the file with the `InputStream`:
1º First the code was like this:

```
private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "assets/credentials.json";
InputStream in = this.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Then I tried opening it from assets:

```
InputStream in = this.getAssets().open("credentials.json");
GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
```

But whatever I try, it gives me `java.io.FileNotFoundException: credentials.json` error, and I'm not sure if it's because of the path name, the way to opening it or what else.

Comment: What is the full error?

Comment: @SteveSmith FileNotFoundException

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: The `InputStream in = ...` one @SteveSmith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigating, I've found how to access the json. 
First was moving the file from `res/assets` to `res/raw`

then change this line:

```
InputStream in = this.getAssets().open("credentials.json");
```

to this one

```
InputStream in = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.credentials);
```

And now the file will be read with no problem